# Duvida Query MySQL

Tags: mysql, query

Estou com uma pequena dúvida e dificuldade em tentar solucionar meu problema, tenho a seguinte query:

```
SELECT
  `PcldCliente`.`id`,
  `PcldCliente`.`nome`,
  `PcldCliente`.`agencia_id`,
  `PcldMain`.`id`,
  `PcldMain`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldMain`.`saldo_devedor`,
  `PcldMain`.`motivo`,
  `PcldMain`.`data_inicio`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`id`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`atual`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`projetado`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`data_inicio`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`id`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`observacao`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`created`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`id`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`anterior`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`atual`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`projetado`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`data_inicio`
FROM
  `mpf`.`pcld_cliente` AS `PcldCliente`
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_main` AS `PcldMain` ON(
    `PcldMain`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id`
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_despesa` AS `PcldDespesa` ON(
    `PcldDespesa`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id`
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_observacoes` AS `PcldObservacoes` ON(
    `PcldObservacoes`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id`
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_saldo` AS `PcldSaldo` ON(
    `PcldSaldo`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id`
  )
WHERE
  `PcldMain`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07' AND `PcldDespesa`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07' AND `PcldSaldo`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07' AND `PcldObservacoes`.`created` = '2016-03-10'
```

O que quero?
Quero retornar todos os Clientes que possuem os registros com as datas inicias, porém quero que retorne todas as Observações para a data especificada, independete de existir ou não. Só que ele retorna somente os que possuem com a data especifica, se não possue o registro na tabela `PcldObservacoes` ele não é retornado e fica de fora.
O que posso fazer?

Comment: Retire seu Where o coloque ele no ON das suas tabelas ...   `ON(
    `PcldMain`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id` AND  `PcldMain`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07' AND `PcldDespesa`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07'`
  )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido!
Como o usuário Marconcilio Souza falou, bastava colocar as codintions no ON ao invés do WHERE!

```
SELECT
  `PcldCliente`.`id`,
  `PcldCliente`.`nome`,
  `PcldCliente`.`agencia_id`,
  `PcldMain`.`id`,
  `PcldMain`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldMain`.`saldo_devedor`,
  `PcldMain`.`motivo`,
  `PcldMain`.`data_inicio`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`id`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`atual`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`projetado`,
  `PcldDespesa`.`data_inicio`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`id`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`anterior`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`atual`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`projetado`,
  `PcldSaldo`.`data_inicio`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`id`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`cliente_id`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`observacao`,
  `PcldObservacoes`.`created`
FROM
  `mpf`.`pcld_cliente` AS `PcldCliente`
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_main` AS `PcldMain` ON(
    `PcldMain`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id` AND `PcldMain`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07'
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_despesa` AS `PcldDespesa` ON(
    `PcldDespesa`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id` AND `PcldDespesa`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07'
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_saldo` AS `PcldSaldo` ON(
    `PcldSaldo`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id` AND `PcldSaldo`.`data_inicio` = '2016-03-07'
  )
LEFT JOIN
  `mpf`.`pcld_observacoes` AS `PcldObservacoes` ON(
    `PcldObservacoes`.`cliente_id` = `PcldCliente`.`id` AND `PcldObservacoes`.`created` = '2016-03-10'
  )
WHERE
  1 = 1
ORDER BY
  `PcldDespesa`.`projetado` DESC
```